# Are there countably many closed manifolds in each dimension?

Tags: manifolds

There is a single closed topological 1-manifold (up to, of course, homeomorphism): $S^1$. The classification of surfaces shows that there are countably many closed topological 2-manifolds. Classification of closed, orientable topological 3-manifolds reveals that there are also a countable number of these, though I am unclear in the non-orientable case. Does every dimension admit only a countable number of closed topological manifolds?

Comment: The comments to this question http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/109881/can-we-prove-that-there-are-countably-many-isomorphism-classes-of-compact-lie-gr imply that there are only countably many closed manifolds in each dimension.  Perhaps you could distill them into one coherent response?

Comment: http://mathoverflow.net/q/198098/40804

Comment: @MikeMiller Perfect. Thanks.

Comment: The answer is yes, proved by Cheeger and Kister - see http://mathoverflow.net/questions/198098/are-there-only-countably-many-compact-topological-manifolds.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Andreas Thom](https://mathoverflow.net/users/8176/andreas-thom) answered this question on MathOverflow [here](https://mathoverflow.net/a/198105/40804):

> It was shown in
>
> J. Cheeger and J. M. Kister, *Counting topological manifolds*. Topology 9, 1970 149–151.
>
> that there are only countably many compact manifolds up to homeomorphism (even allowing boundaries).
>
> Here is a [link](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0040938370900364) to the article.